# Binding a background cell color to a byte[] class property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multibinding

I read a lot of posts about my issue, it seems that multibinding is the best solution, but I can't make it works.

I need to bind a class property, a byte array representing an aRGB color, to a background datagridcell color.

This is my class :

```
public class LedVals
{   ....
    public byte[] ColorT0 { get; set; } = new byte[4] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };
    ....
}
```

To do so I use a custom style :

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ColorPickerColorT0" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RgbConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ColorT0" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Affected like this for the color columns :

```
    private void DgLedTable_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "ColorT0")
        {
            e.Column.CellStyle = (sender as DataGrid).FindResource("ColorPickerColorT0") as Style;

        }
    }
```

I think I'm missing something with Multibinding...

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit :

It works, thanks to Philip W Advice.

Here is the modified style with the converter, dont forget to declare it...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BytetoStringConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" />

----

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ColorPickerColorT0" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=ColorT0, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter} }" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"></Setter>
    </Style>

----
</Window.Resources>
```

And the converter :

```
public class BytetoStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] val = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)value);
        //val = (byte[]) value;
        return Color.FromArgb(val[3], val[2], val[1], val[0]).ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] val = new byte[4];
        Color c = (Color)value;
        val[0] = c.A;
        val[1] = c.R;
        val[2] = c.G;
        val[3] = c.B;

        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need multibinding if you bind to several(!) properties. In your case, you only need to bind to ColorT0, which is a single property, so you need a simple valueconverter (parse the value to a byte[] and convert it to the corresponding color...)

Comment: ok thanks, your right, I don't need multibinding... I'll search how to use value converter.